# How does portrait orientation lock work actually?

Tags: ios, objective-c, user-interface, uiinterfaceorientation

I mean the one from the control center.

Does the iOS simulate supported interface orientation without landscape supported modes, when it is enabled?

Or does it hook autorotation runtime delegate methods?

I have not found any info regarding the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably it operates at system level. The device itself is not reported as rotated out of the orientation(s) that it is locked into. No part of your app is interfered with.

Comment: Note, that it can be locked into portrait mode only with the feature.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that.